# Changing group by toggle title in the header of v-data-table (Vuetify)

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to change group-by toggle title "group" in column header of v-data-table to my own title.

The problem is that vuetify localization file (node_modules/vuetify/es5/locale/ru.js) has no element "group" in dataTable json structure :

[image: Example]

```
......

dataTable: {
    itemsPerPageText: 'Строк на странице:',
    ariaLabel: {
      sortDescending: 'Упорядочено по убыванию.',
      sortAscending: 'Упорядочено по возрастанию.',
      sortNone: 'Не упорядочено.',
      activateNone: 'Активируйте, чтобы убрать сортировку.',
      activateDescending: 'Активируйте для упорядочивания убыванию.',
      activateAscending: 'Активируйте для упорядочивания по возрастанию.'
    },
    sortBy: 'Сортировать по'
  },
  dataFooter: {
    itemsPerPageText: 'Записей на странице:',
    itemsPerPageAll: 'Все',
    nextPage: 'Следующая страница',
    prevPage: 'Предыдущая страница',
    firstPage: 'Первая страница',
    lastPage: 'Последняя страница',
    pageText: '{0}-{1} из {2}'
  },

......
```

How to translate this toggle title element programmatically?